# JS script that automatically captures links

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

i asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351537/javascript-to-return-all-links-in-download-page?noredirect=1#comment124361836_70351537) where i tried to make a JS script that automatically captures links in buttons in downlaod page of edge and save them to clipboard but another problem popped up, the string copied contains only first 5 or 6 links (There are hundreds of links in the page with scrolling aility 'on')

code:

```
    function findButton() {
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
             var arr = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < 100 ;i++) {
     var elem = buttons[i++];
var text = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
     arr.push(text);
 }
      return arr
}

var x = findButton().toString();
setTimeout(function(){navigator.clipboard.writeText(x);},5000);
alert(x);
```

inspect element:

```
<button class="c01209" id="open_link774" role="link" aria-label="https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-94-007-2464-8.pdf">https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-94-007-2464-8.pdf</button>
```

Comment: The links are real anchors or only text inside the button element?

Comment: @LarsFlieger, they are the inner text of button (not `a` element). i will post the inspect element

Comment: Alright. Why do you want to storage them to clipboard?

Comment: @LarsFlieger, i want to paste the result to a text document containing all links that ihave downloaded because i want to make a script that compares these links to the link of any page i open and if it matches any one of them the script will give a warning. just see my first question and you will understand the erason behind this.

Comment: I added an answer. You could simply copy all links from the console. Is that what you want?

Comment: @LarsFlieger, i replied to it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const urls = document.querySelectorAll('button')
const result = Array.from(urls).map(url => url.textContent)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<button role="link" aria-label="https://example-1.com">https://example-1.com</button>
<button role="link" aria-label="https://example-2.com">https://example-2.com</button>
<button role="link" aria-label="https://example-3.com">https://example-3.com</button>
<button role="link" aria-label="https://example-4.com">https://example-4.com</button>
<button role="link" aria-label="https://example-5.com">https://example-5.com</button>
<button role="link" aria-label="https://example-6.com">https://example-6.com</button>
```

Comment: your code worked in the same way mine's too (same result 5 to 6 links). I noticed something, the script captures first 5 to 6 links in the viewed portion of the page (download page has a scroll down bar in the right). +1 for shortening the code.

Comment: @mohamed Can you share the page where you want to grab the links? Probably it's related to a visual render (the page only renders the elements in the viewport)

Comment: it is the downloads page of edge there is no link to it because its just edge://downloads/all (you can open it in the browser) . the whole page is rendered though